# Can I add receptacles on the same circuit as the garage door opener in my garage?

Tags: electrical, wiring, garage, garage-door-opener

I am wanting to add two new outlets on a unfinished wall in my garage. This wall currently has no outlets at all and is a exterior facing wall. I was wondering if i can tie into the outlet in the ceiling that is used for my garage door opener. I believe this outlet is on the same circuit as all other outlets in my garage. I don't plan on running a lot of devices at the same time, just need the extra outlets for ease of use on that side of the garage. I have never had a breaker trip in the garage either. I am wondering if this is allowed? It is the nearest outlet that i can tie into and it would be very easy to do as well. These would be two 15 amp outlets and would be used for light use.

Comment: Without knowing what else is on the circuit, it's impossible to say for sure.  The receptacles will have to be GFCI protected, but that's all I can say with any certainty.

Comment: There is 4 other outlets in my garage that are all on the same circuit. Nothing is running off of them constantly. They are only  being used when i am working in the garage. At most a radio, pancake compressor, saws, other small tools etc. aside from the garage door opener being plugged into the ceiling outlet.

Comment: There is no violation in doing this.  But as @Tester01 mentioned it needs to be GFCI.  And it really doesn't factor in to how many devices are plugged in as you could in essence plug them all into one outlet if that is all you had.  That is only a factor if you will have something that is permanently hooked up.

Comment: Are you sure this circuit only supplies the garage receptacles?

Answer (score 2):

These outlets will need to be GFCI protected if the garage door opener outlet isn't already that way, but yes -- there isn't a limit on how many receptacles can go on a general receptacle circuit.

Do double check to make sure that your circuit doesn't serve something else funky though.

Answer (score -3):

You may be violating code - we don't know the breaker size or the wire gauge to your garage.  Also, you'll know you've got too much loaded on there if the breaker flips every time you try to open or close your garage door.

But short answer is yes, you can.  Just install it properly (tons of youtube videos).

Comment: I've never heard of a garage opener circuit being less than 15A circuit wired with 14 gauge (or larger) wire. Under what circumstance would he be  in violation? Are some garage opening circuits less than 15A? If you suspect that he's violating code, why is the short answer "yes"? How would he know if his plan to add receptacles will violate code?

Comment: It's all 14 gauge wire and on a 15 amp circuit for clarification.

Comment: @ssaltman, The NEC does not specify a limit to how many outlets are allowed on a given circuit.  But I think CEC does though.